# iam new to python getting following error TypeError: must be str, not Tag

Tags: python, django

program

[image]

error

```
F:\aaa\1\homerun>python hometrial.py
product_name: Sunrise Simulator Alarm Clock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hometrial.py", line 33, in <module>
    print("desc: " + desc)
TypeError: must be str, not Tag
```

Comment: error F:\aaa\1\homerun>python hometrial.py
product_name: Sunrise Simulator Alarm Clock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hometrial.py", line 33, in <module>
    print("desc: " + desc)
TypeError: must be str, not Tag

Comment: Please post your code and the traceback formatted as part of the question, do not provide links.  From the previous comment, clearly `desc` is not a string, so you can't use it in concatenation.  Try `str(desc)`, or replace the `+` with a comma.

Comment: Hard to telle that way. Have you tried to convert your desc variable to string `str(desc)` ?

Comment: thank you both for the wonderful answer...it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you say `print("desc:" + desc)`, you are attempting to **concatenate** these 2 values. As `desc` is a type called `Tag`, "desc:" is a string. Either try **casting** `desc` to a string using the `str` function (`str(desc)`),  or giving them as seperate arguments as opposed to concatenating them, by changing the `+` to a `,`.

`print("Desc: ", desc)`
will work just fine :)

#### Why can't it just implicitly convert to a string?

Python is a **strongly typed language**. This means , in simple terms,  operations called on data must be relevant and applicable to the type. For example, trying `my_num = 5 + "5"` will raise a `TypeError`, as adding a string ("5") and integer (5) is not possible. Tag and String are different types, and therefore Python doesn't allow you to concatenate them. In something like JavaScript (a weakly typed language), adding `"5" + 5` will result in 55, as it will implicitly convert `5` to a string and then concatenate them.

Comment: No problem, a pleasure to help. Click the gray "tick mark" next to my answer to mark the question as solved - this should help others see the question has been answered

Comment: Mr. john even i was looking for that to rate your answer...but i didn't know how to thanks again...